# Wkhtmltopdf user permission

Tags: permissions, wkhtmltopdf

I can't seem to get `wkhtmltopdf` to work on a user account.

As root user:

```
wkhtmltopdf -V
wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf
```

Both of the above work. But as a normal user I get an error:

```
wkhtmltopdf -V
wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: libQtWebKit.so.4: cannot open shared     object file: No such file or directory
```

Obviously, `wkhtmltopdf` is working and installed correctly, as it works for the root user, but not for all of the users.

I have tried setting permissions:

```
[root@server ~]# chmod 755 /root/wkqt/
[root@server ~]# chmod 755 /root/wkqt/lib/
[root@server ~]# chmod 755 /root/wkhtmltopdf-qt/
[root@server ~]# chmod 755 /root/wkhtmltopdf-qt/lib/
[root@server ~]# chmod 644 /root/wkqt/lib/*so*
[root@server ~]# chmod 644 /root/wkhtmltopdf-qt/lib/*so*
```

I have also tried adding to `visudo`:

```
motorconne localhost=/bin/wkhtmltopdf
motorconne localhost=/root/wkhtmltopdf-qt/lib/libQtWebKit.so.4
```

but still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: try installing it as the user who intends to use it

Comment: Just guessing, but are the paths correct? Maby root has a folder in it's path that the user doesn't and that's where the shared library sits?

Comment: Can not install as user, error qmake.vars

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact same problem.

You probably followed install steps on the wkhtmltopdf wiki.

It turns out that `libQtWebKit.so.4` is located in `/root/wkqt/lib/` directory.
This means that your user must be authorized to enter into this directory.

However, it is very likely that when you type `cd /root`, you will be denied access to the `root` folder.

The quick and dirty solution is to grant access to your root folder to anyone (yes, I said "quick and dirty"). For instance:

```
sudo chmod a+rx /root
```

Obviously, this is far from perfect. In a perfect world, you would not install the `wkqt` lib in the `root` directory. Instead `/opt/wkqt` would be more appropriate. You can probably do this by changing the `configure` command line when you build `wkhtmltopdf-qt`. For instance:

```
./configure -nomake tools,examples,demos,docs,translations -opensource -prefix "/opt/wkqt"
```

Hope this helps!